# Positioning two boxes inside a LC circuit in Circuitikz

Tags: positioning, boxes, circuitikz

I am trying to introduce two boxes inside an LC circuit, but I encounter two problems: the first concerns the positioning of these two boxes, I cannot align them perfectly with the node, I cannot find the right value to give on the position, the second it concerns the box on the right where I cannot send the "cavity" on a new line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0) -- (2,0)
            (0,2) -- (2,2)
            (0,0) to[C, l^=$C$] (0,2)
            (2,0) to[L, l^=$L$] (2,2)
            (0.5,2) -- (0.5,2.5)
            (1.5,2) -- (1.5,2.5)
            (-1,2.5) -- (0.5,2.5)
            (3, 2.5) -- (1.5,2.5)
            node[draw,rectangle] at (-1.5,2.5){V}
            node[draw,rectangle] at (3,2.5){E.M. \\ Cavity};
        \end{circuitikz}
        \label{fig:lc-circuit-cavity}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm not very familiar with this package, but I needed it to make a series of circuits.

Comment: Can you show us a sketch what you after? Your document example has error in last node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure guessing, what you like to draw:

[image]

Is this correct image?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{circuitikz}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0)   to[C=$C$] ++ (0, 2) -- ++ ( 2,0) 
                    to[L=$L$] ++ (0,-2) -- ++ (-2,0)
            %
            (0.5,2) |- ++ (-1.5,0.5) node[left, draw] {V}
            (1.5,2) |- ++ ( 1.5,0.5) node[right,draw, align=center] {E.M.\\ Cavity};
        \end{circuitikz}
        \label{fig:lc-circuit-cavity}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Package `circuitikz` is based on `tikz` package. This means, that you `circuitikz˙` scheme you can use any of elements defined in `tikz` package.

In package `circuitikz` are defined elements of electrical circuits. They form two families: *path-style components* and * node style* components. In your case are used *path style. They you  ca draw as `\draw (<coordinate 1>) to [component name and annotations>] (<coordinate 2>)`. To them you can append elements  from `tikz` as is done in above MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\draw (<coordinate 1>) to [component name and annotations>] (<coordinate 2>) node [right] {<text>}`
```

where node can has any of style provided by `tikz`.

At drawing you can use absolute coordinate (as you do in your MWE) or relative as is used in above MWE. It is draw in two parts. In the first is a "loop" with C and L  connected by lines, in the second parts are drawn lines with nodes at the end. Lines are drawn with orthogonal connection (used are `|-` path with the same meaning as they have in `tikz` images)

Details of them yo can find in the package documentation.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. But you use a different approach, can I learn this from circuitikz package?

Comment: @Frostman `circuitikz` is just a `tikzpicture`, all `circuitikz` does is add many shapes and functionality to draw circuits. The shown syntax can be learned from the `pgfmanual` or other introductory material to Ti*k*Z.